# Parsing Many-to-Many XML in Android

Tags: android, xml, sqlite, jdom-2

I am trying to parse an XML file in android and then save contents to a SQLite Database.  I am currently using JDOM2 for ease in reading the code.  As far as memory concerns I don't believe JDOM will be an issue as the parsing happens fairly quickly on my Galaxy Nexus which would be on the lower end of supported devices.  When the relationship is One-to-One, I have no issues getting the data, saving it to the Sqlite database and reading it/generating a listview with the data.  However, I am drawing a blank as to how I'm going to do this for One-to-Many and Many-to-Many as all of the tutorials for parsing XML I have come across use a One-to-One XML structure.  As an Example, the XML code I need to parse looks something like this:

```
<Name name="Name 1">
    <Location>XYZ</Location>
    <Type>XYZ</Type>
    <Item name="Item 1">
        <SubItem name="XYZ"></SubItem>
        <SubItem name="XYZ"></SubItem>
    </Item>
    <Item name="Item 2">
        <SubItem name="XYZ"></SubItem>
        <SubItem name="XYZ"></SubItem>
    </Item>
</Name>
<Name name="Name 2">
    <Location>XYZ</Location>
    <Type>XYZ</Type>
    <Item name="Item 1">
        <SubItem name="XYZ"></SubItem>
        <SubItem name="XYZ"></SubItem>
    </Item>
    <Item name="Item 2">
        <SubItem name="XYZ"></SubItem>
        <SubItem name="XYZ"></SubItem>
    </Item>
</Name>
```

I am able to get all the Names, Locations and Types easily since there is only a One-to-One relationship between all of those.  They are saved in 1 table of my database.  What I need to do is save all the Items and SubItems in their own tables and still link it to the right name.  This is posing a problem for me and it is likely the logic that is throwing me off.

If I need to use a different parser, that is fine as I am able to get the same information as I have above using XMLPullParser, but I do like the brevity and cleanliness of JDOM2 as an entry level developer tackling both XML and Sqlite for the first time together.

I'm not concerned about how long it is going to take to actually perform the operation.  If the user chooses to import their data into the app, it would likely be a one-time process and something I burry into the menu.  I also cannot change the format of the XML as it is being generated by a 3rd party program and this is the format they chose to export the data.